# How do I round a DateTime to the nearest Period

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to be able to round any given Instant to the nearest Period to 
support grouping of data.

i.e. someone might want to group by 2 week periods, so given an 
Instant, I want to be able to work out the nearest instant (before or 
after) on the period boundary where "now" is considered to be the end 
of the current period. If today is Tuesday, then consider that this 2 
week Period ends this week. Given any date (from now backward) I'd 
like to calculate the "2 week Period" that it fits in to.

```
// pseudo code

Period sevenDays = Days.SEVEN;

Instant nearestWeek = sevenDays.roundToNearest(new DateTime());

Period twelveHours = Hours.hours(12);

Instant nearestHalfDay = twelveHours.roundToNearest(new DateTime());
```

I hope that makes sense, any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, this is one solution I made myself but I really think this functionality should be built into Joda Time.

```
public static DateTime dateTimeFloor(DateTime dt, Period p) {
    if (p.getYears() != 0) {
        return dt.yearOfEra().roundFloorCopy().minusYears(dt.getYearOfEra() % p.getYears());
    } else if (p.getMonths() != 0) {
        return dt.monthOfYear().roundFloorCopy().minusMonths((dt.getMonthOfYear() - 1) % p.getMonths());
    } else if (p.getWeeks() != 0) {
        return dt.weekOfWeekyear().roundFloorCopy().minusWeeks((dt.getWeekOfWeekyear() - 1) % p.getWeeks());
    } else if (p.getDays() != 0) {
        return dt.dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy().minusDays((dt.getDayOfMonth() - 1) % p.getDays());
    } else if (p.getHours() != 0) {
        return dt.hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy().minusHours(dt.getHourOfDay() % p.getHours());
    } else if (p.getMinutes() != 0) {
        return dt.minuteOfHour().roundFloorCopy().minusMinutes(dt.getMinuteOfHour() % p.getMinutes());
    } else if (p.getSeconds() != 0) {
        return dt.secondOfMinute().roundFloorCopy().minusSeconds(dt.getSecondOfMinute() % p.getSeconds());
    }
    return dt.millisOfSecond().roundCeilingCopy().minusMillis(dt.getMillisOfSecond() % p.getMillis());
}
```

Comment: Nice, but this only works as long as exactly one field of the period is used. For example, a period of 1m30s would be rounded to the nearest minute.